# The old "how to fold XML" question

Tags: xml, nxml, outline

I'm doing quite a bit of manual XML editing (the source definition of some code generation I'm doing is a custom XML format) and of course prefer to use Emacs over any special purpose  (usually ugly) XML editors. nXml mode has stood me well in the past, but I cannot get my head around its "outline" support. Various internet and SO posts effectively say nothing - I'm wondering if anyone has any practical experience with outlining/folding XML in Emacs (any mode) whether or not that requires altering the XML structure itself.

Comment: Look into outshine.

Comment: Here is a link to an example I did a while back dealing with folding code for arbitrary tags in nxml mode -- perhaps it could help you develop your own code:  http://superuser.com/a/787030/206164  The particular tag I tackled was `xsl` -- I incorporated a counter to deal with nested tags with the same name.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I found this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944614/emacs-does-hideshow-work-with-xml-mode-sgml-mode

```lisp
(require 'hideshow)
(require 'sgml-mode)
(require 'nxml-mode)

(add-to-list 'hs-special-modes-alist
             '(nxml-mode
               "<!--\\|<[^/>]*[^/]>"
               "-->\\|</[^/>]*[^/]>"

               "<!--"
               sgml-skip-tag-forward
               nil))



(add-hook 'nxml-mode-hook 'hs-minor-mode)

;; optional key bindings, easier than hs defaults
(define-key nxml-mode-map (kbd "C-c h") 'hs-toggle-hiding)
```

You can use the code from there, slightly modified, for nxml-mode easily.

This will allow you to toggle hiding/unhiding of xml elements with <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> and will support underscores in the names.

[image]

Comment: typo: `nxml`, not `nmxl`

Comment: @SeanAllred: I fixed the typo.  The cut-and-pasters will thank you for the catch!

Comment: Brilliant! It also looks like it will be easy to write custom functions for `hideshow` like scanning a buffer to toggle all instances of a given tag etc. Would also be nice if clicking on an ellipsis with a mouse would un-hide, but I'll try not to shave the yak too much :)

Comment: @MarkAufflick hideshow has mouse support, by default, shift + mouse 2 is bound to hs-mouse-toggle-hiding, which should work exactly like you want it to.

Comment: +1000.  This answer saved my sanity.  I love nxml-mode but was switching constantly between it and a dedicated XML editor just for the latter's tag-folding support.  I wonder, though, if it'd be possible to implement this functionality using the same library as [dirtree.el](https://github.com/zk/emacs-dirtree), which supports fold/unfold with the mouse and line-drawing of the tree structure in GUI Emacsen?

Comment: Don't understand the necessity for `sgml-skip-tag-forward`. I replaced it with `nil`. In Emacs 25.3 `forward-sexp-function` is `nxml-forward-balanced-item`

Comment: How can I hide a node instead of folding it?

Answer (score 13):

[`web-mode`](http://web-mode.org/) has element folding built in and bound to `C-c C-f`. But you will lose some of the features of using `nxml-mode` obviously.

Comment: I did not know about web-mode (don't do much web dev these days). I'll try it out and report back, thanks.

Comment: So close! Unfortunately web-mode doesn't allow for underscores in xml tag names (which we use). Littered throughout the web-mode code are hundreds of near-same hard coded regex strings. I had a stab at working out which should be modified but it because exhausting! Otherwise, the folding in web-mode does indeed work :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a quite wonderful gem called `noxml-fold-mode` that exactly helps with that.

https://github.com/paddymcall/noxml-fold

It can do folding and it also has visibility cycling.

Answer (score -1):

```
(add-to-list
 'hs-special-modes-alist
 '(nxml-mode
   "<!--\\|<[^/>][^>]*>" "-->\\|</[^/>]+>" "<!--" #'nxml-forward-element nil))
(add-hook 'nxml-mode-hook #'hs-minor-mode)
;; (setcdr (assoc 'nxml-mode hs-special-modes-alist) (list "<!--\\|<[^/>][^>]*>" "-->\\|</[^/>]+>" "<!--" #'nxml-forward-element nil))
```