# How do I get a compact view html tags in emacs?

Tags: html

I an emacs newbie and I generally write a lot html code(~800 lines in one file). Now I want to a compact view to the completed tags. An example of this would be:

```
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
   <div class="text-left">
     <div id="canvas-holder">
        <canvas id="chart-area3">
        </canvas><br>
     </div><br><br>
     <p class="text-center">Bachelor of Science</p>
   </div>
 </div><!-- End of col-md-4 col-sm-6 chart3 div -->
```

This code appears like this:

```
[+]<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">...</div><!-- End of col-md-4 col-sm-6 chart3 div -->
```

Well not exactly same but you get the idea. How can I achieve this?
Please also give some details of the key-bindings associated as well/

Comment: **The old “how to fold XML” question**: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/3157/2287

Comment: @lawlist This works well for me. However how can I use this in html-mode using the same binding "C-c h"?